# Como mostrar os produtos favoritados e não favoritado de uma tabela pelo id?

Tags: node.js, react, typescript, lógica

Como é possível mostrar os produtos favoritados daquele determinado usuário através de um filtro, onde possa mostrar se aquele produto foi favoritado ou se ele não favoritado, indicando uma condicional.

Por exemplo: Eu tenho 4 produtos registrados, daqueles 4 produtos eu favoritei 3, logo aquele único que não favoritei deverá me apresentar que ainda não favoritado através de uma mensagem.

Meu sistema está seguindo essa lógica: tenho duas tabelas produto e favoritos, quando estou fazendo a requisição de favoritos, ele retorna os produtos favoritos somente através daquele cliente.

Requisição GET - PRODUTO

```
[
    {
        "id_produto": 5,
        "titulo_produto": "Camisa do Messi1",
        "descricao_produto": "camisa do Messi",
        "preco_produto": 5001,
        "estoque_produto": 30051,
        "categoria_id": 5,
        "tb_categorium": {
            "id_categoria": 5,
            "titulo_categoria": "Camisa",
            "descricao_categoria": "Descrição geral sobre camisa"
        }
    },
    {
        "id_produto": 6,
        "titulo_produto": "Camisa do Neymar1",
        "descricao_produto": "camisa do Neymar1",
        "preco_produto": 5001,
        "estoque_produto": 3001,
        "categoria_id": 5,
        "tb_categorium": {
            "id_categoria": 5,
            "titulo_categoria": "Camisa",
            "descricao_categoria": "Descrição geral sobre camisa"
        }
    },
    {
        "id_produto": 7,
        "titulo_produto": "Camisa do Mbappe1",
        "descricao_produto": "camisa do Mbappe",
        "preco_produto": 500,
        "estoque_produto": 300,
        "categoria_id": 6,
        "tb_categorium": {
            "id_categoria": 6,
            "titulo_categoria": "Chinelo",
            "descricao_categoria": "Descrição geral sobre chinelo"
        }
    }
]
```

Requisição GET - Favorito

```
[
    {
        "id_favorito": 8,
        "status_favorito": "p",
        "cliente_id": 4,
        "produto_id": 5,
        "tb_produto": {
            "id_produto": 5,
            "titulo_produto": "Camisa do Messi1",
            "descricao_produto": "camisa do Messi",
            "preco_produto": 5001,
            "estoque_produto": 30051,
            "categoria_id": 5
        },
        "tb_cliente": {
            "id_cliente": 4,
            "nome_cliente": "Mateus de Sousa Maciel",
            "email_cliente": "mateus@gmail.com",
            "senha_cliente": "$2a$10$ZYPszI.3hp/fIkvxTwQJDeny39bJ1Ke47UCau6PeQh6LykhbS5/j.",
            "tipo_cliente": 1,
            "cpf_cliente": "098.890.678-90",
            "telefone_cliente": "(85) 99278 - 8900",
            "endereco_cliente": "Rua José de Emanuel Oliveira, 68"
        }
    },
    {
        "id_favorito": 9,
        "status_favorito": "p",
        "cliente_id": 4,
        "produto_id": 6,
        "tb_produto": {
            "id_produto": 6,
            "titulo_produto": "Camisa do Neymar1",
            "descricao_produto": "camisa do Neymar1",
            "preco_produto": 5001,
            "estoque_produto": 3001,
            "categoria_id": 5
        },
        "tb_cliente": {
            "id_cliente": 4,
            "nome_cliente": "Mateus de Sousa Maciel",
            "email_cliente": "mateus@gmail.com",
            "senha_cliente": "$2a$10$ZYPszI.3hp/fIkvxTwQJDeny39bJ1Ke47UCau6PeQh6LykhbS5/j.",
            "tipo_cliente": 1,
            "cpf_cliente": "098.890.678-90",
            "telefone_cliente": "(85) 99278 - 8900",
            "endereco_cliente": "Rua José de Emanuel Oliveira, 68"
        }
    }
]
```

Quando o usuário estiver logado, ele vai buscar os produtos favoritados somente daquele usuário (lógica usada no back-end).

**Situação Chave:** (Usando React TypeScript)

Estou tentando filtrar no react a situação da seguinte forma:

```
{favoritos.map((favorito, index) => (
   favorito.produto_id === dado.id_produto ? (
       <C.Icone key={index}
           className="fa fa-star" cor="#FECE3F"
       />
   ):"não favoritado!"
))}
```

> Observação: (dado.id_produto) faz parte do Map de produtos que está sendo referenciado sobre todo esse map acima, ou seja, map de favoritos está entre o inicio e o fim do map de produtos.

Mas ele retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria que ele retornasse apenas um valor, onde os produtos favoritados aparecesse uma estrela e um produto não favoritado, mostrasse: uma estrela cinza.

Comment: O problema neste caso é mais lógica. Seria melhor retornar apenas uma lista e nela ter um campo para afirmar se é favorito ou não. No back-end, você poderia usar o sistema de relacionamento (many-to-many, many-to-one) do banco de dados (se for relacional)

Comment: Entendi, valeu!